# OLDB connection string to connect Cloud SQL db

Tags: vba, azure-sql-database, oledb

I am looking for the connection string to connect to SQL server on Azure Cloud
used below string to connect to SQL user

```
OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=#DATASOURCE#;Initial Catalog=#CATALOG#;UID=userid;Password=pwd;
```

this is working fine. but when I try connecting with windows user I need to update the connection string as

```
ODBC;Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=#DATASOURCE#;Initial Catalog=#CATALOG#;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;UID=myemailid
```

Is there a way I can use OLEDB driver to connect using windows authentication?
thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we can't. Azure SQL database doesn't support Windows authentication for now.

Azure SQL Database only supports two types of authentication: [SQL Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode#connecting-through-sql-server-authentication) and [Azure Active Directory Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview).

No matter which driver you use to connect the Azure SQL database, the windows authentication won't work.

For more details, please ref this document: [Authorize database access to SQL Database, SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/logins-create-manage#authentication)

Comment: Thanks Leon
I am able to connect to db using Azure AD Authentication but for that I have to use ODBC driver.  Is there a way I can use OLE DB driver with AD Authentication?

Comment: @ShubhadaManole you're welcome, please ref this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/features/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @ShubhadaManole If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @ShubhadaManole,hope you're doing well, do you have any other concerns?

Comment: Thanks you so much Leon
I could able to connect using below string from the reference you shared :)
Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=[server];Initial Catalog=[database];Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated;Use Encryption for Data=true